# R: plot multiple lines in one plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, time-series

I have three data frames `df1`, `df2`, `df3` in the following format

```
datetime               value
2012-01-02 00:00:00    1.2
2012-01-02 00:15:00    1.7
2012-01-02 00:30:00    0.5
2012-01-02 00:45:00    0.8


datetime               value
2012-01-03 00:00:00    0.4
2012-01-03 00:15:00    1.1
2012-01-03 00:30:00    1.8
2012-01-03 00:45:00    0.7

datetime               value
2012-01-04 00:00:00    2.9
2012-01-04 00:15:00    0.7
2012-01-04 00:30:00    1.3
2012-01-04 00:45:00    0.3
```

All three data frames have different dates, the `datetime` is in `POSIXlt` format.

Since, time index are same, I want to plot all the lines on the same plot. But I am not sure how to extract time only. I have done following so far:

```
library(chron)
timeOnly = times(format(df1$datetime, "%H:%M:%S"))
plot(timeOnly, df1$value)
```

But the x-axis tick labels go from `0 to 1`, instead of `00:00:00 to 23:45:00`

Comment: I answered without exactly the same data, but I think is the answer you are looking for

Comment: @chintans I noticed a typo in your last line. You defined the times you want as "timeOnly1" but then you put "timeOnly" in the plot function. Perhaps you defined timeOnly differently than timeOnly1? I ran the same code but with plot(timeOnly1, df1$value) and got the correct x-axis.

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed the typo. But I want the x-axis to be `00:00 to 23:45`. How to get that?

Comment: Wow this is surprisingly tough. The axis wants to autoformat to 0-1 once you include the whole range of times. Well, it seems like you have 96 observations per vector. Once crude approach would be to limit the original plot and then add on the extras like this: plot(x[1:93], y[1:93]); points(x, y). This obviously won't look perfect though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited to have different dates, This is how I would solve it, add a class, and then rbind the dataframes and plot it:

```
library(lubridate)
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(date_time = seq(ymd_hm('2012-01-02 00:00'),ymd_hm('2012-01-02 23:45'), by = '15 min')
              , value = rnorm(4, mean = 1, sd =0.2), class = "a")
set.seed(2)
df2 <- data.frame(date_time = seq(ymd_hm('2012-01-03 00:00'),ymd_hm('2012-01-03 23:45'), by = '15 min')
              , value = rnorm(4, mean = 1, sd =0.2), class = "b")
set.seed(3)
df3 <- data.frame(date_time = seq(ymd_hm('2012-01-04 00:00'),ymd_hm('2012-01-04 23:45'), by = '15 min')
              , value = rnorm(4, mean = 1, sd =0.2), class = "c")


df <- rbind(df1,df2, df3)
df$time <- as_date(hm(paste(hour(df$date_time),minute(df$date_time), sep=":")))
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = value)) + geom_line(aes(color = class))+ scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%H %M")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but you have kept same date in all data frames. In my case, all three data frames have different dates.

Comment: sorry@chintans, I see what you need, be back in a second

Comment: ready @chintans I fixed it, you use different dates and makes the same plot, look how I changed the dates of the data frame and still works

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work, except the following problem: In my plot, I get xtick labels as `Jan 01 00:00, Jan 01 06:00, Jan 01 12:00, Jan 01 18:00, Jan 02 00:00`. I would like the xtick labels to be what you have.

But when I copy and paste your code, I get the same same result as you have.

Comment: Add the following code at the end `+ scale_x_date(date_labels = "%H %M")`

Comment: Thanks Derek. The code looks as follow: `ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = value)) + geom_line(aes(color = class)) + scale_x_date(date_labels = "%H %M")`, but I get the following error `Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only`

Comment: Weird, you did this part? `df$time <- as_date(hm(paste(hour(df$date_time),minute(df$date_time), sep=":")))`

Comment: Yep, I did that. In your code, change the end time to `23:45` instead of `00:45`, for all the 3 data frames. Then you will see the output with full date.

Comment: OK mate figured it out, this is the solution `df$time <- as_date(hm(paste(hour(df$date_time),minute(df$date_time), sep=":")))
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = value)) + geom_line(aes(color = class))+ scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%H %M")` sorry about the mixup

Comment: I will add this to the answer

Comment: You are a star!, I will accept the answer. Just change `00:45` to `23:45`.

Comment: @chintans  changed it to 23:45. by the way, in case you don't know in r you can use the `dput()` function to replicate your data, if you dont want to give it all away you can use `dput(head(yourdata))`.